I can't install pip due to malformed docker sources
When I enter: sudo apt install pip
I get this error:
E: Invalid value set for option Signed-By regarding source
https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/ noble (not a fingerprint)
E: The list of sources could not be read
How can solve this error and install pip on Ubuntu_24.04_LTS?

The docker repository has nothing to do with pip.
First, remove the docker repository using the Software & Updates tool (uncheck docker repo in Other Software tab). In case Software & Updates crashes, open the the folder /etc/apt/sources.list.d/, and then delete the .list file corresponding to the docker repository using termianl sudo rm /path/to/docker-file.list.
Then, run the command
sudo apt update

Then, install pip with
sudo apt install python3-pip


The Software & Updates tool can't start and gives crash error also gives docker web addres in error page.

Thanks. Now pip is working

You can click on the checkmark to accept my answer, if it works for you
